# Clone a back and white image to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When uploading to wordpress I want to save the image twice, once in black and white and once as its default. I have the following code which does this:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','bw_images_size');
function bw_images_size() {
    add_image_size('themename-bw-image', get_option('thumbnail_size_w'), get_option('thumbnail_size_h'), false);
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','themename_bw_filter');
function themename_bw_filter($meta) {
    $file = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = trailingslashit($file['path']).$meta['sizes']['themename-bw-image']['file'];
    list($orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type) = @getimagesize($file);
    $image = wp_load_image($file);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    switch ($orig_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            imagepng( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            imagejpeg( $image, $file );
            break;
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

The problem is that it saved a black and white version at the thumbnail size, but I want it to save it at the original size. I know this happens at the following line:

```
add_image_size('themename-bw-image', get_option('thumbnail_size_w'), get_option('thumbnail_size_h'), false);
```

But I dont know how to get the original size here. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are specifying the size of themename-bw-image to be the same as a thumbnail.

Instead, use a larger size, e.g.

```
add_image_size('themename-bw-image', get_option('large_size_w'), get_option('large_size_h'), false);
```